# Delete all nodes from database except from user1 and admin

Tags: database

I have got thousands of junk entries in my Drupal 6 website. Is there a way I can Delete all nodes from database accept from user1 and admin.

I also want to delete all users accept user1 and admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do that with

[views_bulk_operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

It will delete the nodes and users progressively using the Batch API.

- Create a content / node based View
- Add the bulk operations field
- Configure bulk operations field to add "Delete item'
- Add filters to View to exclude content from user1 / admin
- Run the View, check to select all rows, and bulk delete the relevant nodes.

Repeat using a user-based View to delete users.

Note, prior to deleting users, check the account cancellation settings at `Admin > Configuration > Account settings > Registration and cancellation`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have though run this on phpMyadmin delete from nodes where uid not in (1,3) but this also removes the uid 0 which I think is for anonymous users. can we recreate uid 0

Comment: I'd advise you to use VBO instead otherwise too much risk of broken / orphaned data in the db (i.e your current situation) For now, recreate anon user with: `insert into users (name, pass, mail, theme, signature, language, init, timezone) values ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');`
`update users set uid = 0 where name = '';` and then use VBO